# C++ shallow/deep copy?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, deep-copy

I have this function

```
int getrelation(string name, RELATION& output){

        bool found=0;
        int index=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a_attributes.size();i++){
            if(name==a_attributes[i].str_name){
                found=1;
                index=i;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            printf("relation not found");
            return 1;
        }
        output=a_attributes[index];  

        return 0;
    }
```

RELATION is a class
a_attributes is a vector of relations.

its supposed to return a reference to the relation object.  After `getrelation()` is called, if i change the values of output, then the values of `a_attributes[index]` should also be changed because this is a shallow copy, right?

Comment: I think you pressed the "Post Answer" button before you got to the bit where you asked a question. Have a read of the [faq] to learn about what makes a good question.

Comment: There is no question here.   Questions end with a question mark (?).

Comment: The only thing C++ here is the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your assignment operator, which isn't listed here.

The line

`output=a_attributes[index];`

will use the assignment operator to set output. If that assignment operator makes a deep copy, then a deep copy is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't overloaded the assignment operator, then no, you will not get a shallow copy. When you assign `output=a_attributes[index];`, you are making a copy of `a_attributes[index]`. Thus, any modifications to the returned value will not affect `a_attributes`.

If you want a shallow copy, then you would have to either [overload the assignment operator](http://www.umsl.edu/~subramaniana/overload4.html), or pass a pointer by reference, by changing the argument to `RELATION& *output`, and passing in a pointer, then changing the last line to `output=&a_attributes[index];`.

There is also another problem with your code. You can't compare strings directly with `==` like you have in the line `if(name==a_attributes[i].str_name)`, because it will only return true if the strings are stored in the same location. You need to use something like [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/).

Answer (score 0):

No, because what you here is a deep copy. The `output` parameter is a reference to some object of class `RELATION`. So if you change that object in `getrelation` function then the user will notice those changes, because you change a referenced object. However, on this line - `output=a_attributes[index];` you essentially invoke a copy assignment operator of the object `output`, which does a deep copy of every field from object returned by `a_attributes[index]` to the object referenced by `output`, unless copy assignment operator is overloaded and does something different. This is basically because you cannot change a value of the reference - for example, it cannot be referencing one object and end up referencing another. To achieve what you want (if I get you right), you have to pass a pointer to pointer to the object (or a reference to a pointer), then you can change a pointer to the object by de-referencing it. Something like this:

```
int getrelation(string name, RELATION **output){
        bool found=0;
        int index=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a_attributes.size();i++){
            if(name==a_attributes[i].str_name){
                found=1;
                index=i;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            printf("relation not found");
            return 1;
        }
        *output= &a_attributes[index];
        return 0;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

No ... if you want to get a reference to the output object, then pass a reference-to-a-pointer of type `RELATION` to the function, not a reference-to-an-object of type `RELATION`.

For instance:

```
int getrelation(string name, RELATION*& output)
{
    bool found=0;
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a_attributes.size();i++){
        if(name==a_attributes[i].str_name){
            found=1;
            index=i;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        printf("relation not found");
        return 1;
    }
    output = &(a_attributes[index]);  //take the address-of object

    return 0;
}
```

You would then call your function like so:

```
RELATION* ptr_to_object = NULL;
string argument_name;
//...more code to initialize argument_name

if (getrelation(argument_name, ptr_to_object) == 1)
{
    //...handle error condition
}

//now ptr_to_object points to your a_attribute[index] object
```

So at this point, you can now dereference `ptr_to_object`, and you will get the object at `a_attribute[index]`.  You can then change the attributes of that object through dereferencing the pointer.  The only warning is that you should not call `delete` on `ptr_to_object` since it does not "own" the object being pointed to, and the pointer being returned does not point to the beginning of a memory segment that was allocated with `new`.  Furthermore if the container `a_attribute` disposes of the object (i.e., if it's a `std::map` or `std::vector`), then the pointer will be pointing to an invalid memory location.  So you have to make sure the container out-lives the pointer you're using as a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more idiomatic C++ although returning the actual iterator could be a good idea as well.

```
struct rel_by_name : public std::binary_function<const std::string&, const RELATION&, bool> {
  bool operator()(const std::string& s, const RELATION& rel) {
    return s == rel.str_name;
  }
};

RELATION& getrelation(const std::string& name) {
  std::vector<RELATION>::iterator it = std::find_if(a_attributes.begin(), a_attributes.end(),
                                                    std::bind1st(rel_by_name(), name));
  if(it == a_attributes.end()) {
    //not found, report error by throwing or something
  }
  else { return *it; }
}
```

You might want to add a const overload returning a `const Relation&`.